# TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that injects code into the current tab. It has been working fine, but suddenly I've received an error without making any changes to that part of the code.

**Error:**    *Error handling response: TypeError: chrome.tabs.executeScript is not a function
at...*

**Code:**

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
  let tab = tabs[0];
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    {
      code: 'document.querySelector("#twotabsearchtextbox").value',
    },
    display_search // my own function
  );
});
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "name": "chrome extension",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Bamboo",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "/images/icon.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "/images/icon.png"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If your extension is not ManifestV3, then show your manifest.json and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm my extension is ManifestV3, but the question you linked is using chrome.scripting instead of chrome.tabs. I don't understand the difference? I have shared my manifest

Comment: `scripting` is the solution for ManifestV3.